# interpret float bits as long in java?

Tags: java, optimization, types, casting, floating-point

Tt is not a normal "type casting".

I just want to have an equivalent of Java for :

```
long i;
float  y;
i  = * ( long * ) &y;// C code
```

some ppl may guess i just want try 
[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

This is C code, the question is how to make it in Java  since no pointers and references are there
yeah i implemented it and works way faster as 1/Math.sqrt(), while having an error first on the 4rth sign!!

Comment: nice exercise on the beginning, what is Your question?

Comment: This is C code, the question is how to make it in Java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The static method [`Float.floatToRawIntBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits-float-) does exactly that. There is also [`Float.floatToIntBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits-float-) that has slightly different `NaN` handling semantics.

The inverse transformation is [`Float.intBitsToFloat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat-int-).

In case you're wondering why it's `int` and not `long`, Java `int` is 32-bits wide (as is `float`).

Comment: What is the effective difference between a Java `int` and a C `int` due to the # of bits?

Comment: thanks, that was an answer. 
Difference is that C float could be 64-bits long as you see in the example on my link above, and there you must convert float to long and use 64x magical digit

Comment: @RandallArms: In C, there is no fixed size for `int`. It is implementation (and generally platform) dependent.

Comment: @user8426627: Yes, float could be 64 bit in C (although it hardly ever is), but long could be 32 bit as well. This is platform dependent, although currently many C implementations use IEEE-754 floating point types.